# debug port problem while running Lauterbach CMM script

Tags: trace32, lauterbach

Currently Im developing Lauterbach CMM scripts to automate test cases for SPC58NG84
As part of Test case:
- Need to reset target system before and after test case.
- Need to read and wrte variable values from C code.

When I run test scripts I got error 'debug port problem' and in 'watch window' all variable values showing BUS ERROR.

Can you please let me know how to debug this issue?.

What are the reasons causing 'debug port problem'?

Error Message in Area winodw:
CO:2 error: CPU suddenly left debug mode (OSR=0x3C1)
CO:0 JTAGID=0x11110041
Warning: CO:1 Core currently in reset. Stopping core on activation.

CMM Script:
**Test Pre condition: Reset target**

```
 Break.Delete
 WAIT 100.ms
 SYStem.Mode Down
 SYStem.DETECT.CPU
 SYStem.Mode Up
 B:: Go
 WAIT 500.ms
```

**Test case Execution:**
--Read and write Variables in software-----

**Test Post condition: Reset target**

```
 Break
 Break.Delete
 WAIT 100.ms
 SYStem.Mode Down
 SYStem.Mode Up
 B:: Go
 WAIT 1000.ms
```

Answer (score 1):

The error 'debug port problem' after the Break command usually means that the target application crashed so badly that core does not respond to the debugger's halt command anymore.

In order to debug the problem, make sure that your boot loader sets up the interrupt vector start address (IVPR) as early as possible, and also put branch-to-self instructions to all interrupt handler addresses, unless interrupt handler code already exists.

Once this is done, set program preakpoints to the interrupt handlers typically involved in crashes: machine check, data storage, instruction storage, program interrupt. Doing so should catch the core when the crash occurs, and the SRR0 (CSRR or MCSRR, depending on interrupt type) will show you at which address the problem occurred.